# null variables out of onDataChange method

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently developing an android app where I'm using firebase as database but when in got the variable in the `onDataChange` method and I assign them to a global variables I got null variables but when I call those variables in the `onDataChange` method they are not null.

```
public class PositionateMarkerTask extends AsyncTask {
    public ArrayList<Location> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    public void connect() {
        //setting connexion parameter
        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/test");
        Query query = ref.orderByChild("longitude");

        //get the data from the DB
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //checking if the user exist
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //get each user which has the target username
                        Location location =userSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
                            arrayList.add(location);
                        //if the password is true , the data will be storaged in the sharedPreferences file and a Home activity will be launched
                    }
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("not found");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                  System.out.println("problem ");

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        connect();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);

        System.out.println("the firs long is"+arrayList.get(0).getLongitude());

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same problem. Just pass the arraylist values inside the onDataChange to another method.

```
 myFirebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.d("FIREBASE",String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));


            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Log.d("FIREBASE ","FOR LOOP");


                    //Arraylist codes
                    iosTitleVal.add(snapshot.getKey().toString());
                    iosDescVal.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("FIREBASE","ArrayList KEY IS "+iosTitleVal);

                 //Passing arraylist values to another method 
                    storageContainer(iosTermTitle,iosTermDesc);

                }

            }else {

                Log.d("FIREBASE","NO DATAS");

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here's my **storageContainer** method. In this method I passed the arrraylist values to RecyclerView Adapter's constructor.

```
public void storageContainer(ArrayList<String> arrayListTitle, ArrayList<String> arrayListDesc){


   iosTitleStorage = arrayListTitle;
   iosDescStorage = arrayListDesc;


    //No null exception here...
     Log.d("FIREBASE"," My Data KEY "+iosTitleStorage +" and VAL "+iosDescStorage);

 }
```

I hope it'll work